# ask for number of array element on click

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to know if its possible to log the number of the array-element by click.
I have like over 100 elements in an array:

```
var cubesmixed = []; 
var cubes;
for(var i = 0; i < 143; i++) {
    cubes = paper.rect(Math.floor(Math.random()*2000), Math.floor(Math.random()*2000), 0, 0);
    cubes.animate({ width: 25, height: 25 }, 500, "bounce");
    cubesmixed.push(cubes);
}
```

which are all svg-objects. On click I would like to get, as mentioned before, the number of that element.

`$(this).click(function() { console.log(index of current element in cubes) });`

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `cubes.indexOf(element)`?

Comment: @Jeffman no I would like to get the index of the current clicked element inside the array.

Comment: Maybe you should post what some of the real array looks like, and the corresponding HTML. Seriously, I am baffled and losing interest.

Comment: I think that you try to achieve something in a totally bad way

Comment: Use an array to log the IDs of every cube that's created. On click, look up the clicked cube's ID in the array for the index position.

Comment: Can you also show where you assign the click handlers?

Answer (score 0):

**Try jQuery's [`$.inArray`()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method**

```
var that = this;
$(this).click(function() { 
    var indexInArray = $.inArray(that, cubes);
    console.log(indexInArray);
});
```

You will get a 0 based index of the position of that element in your array, or -1 if no match is found.

Comment: thanks for your edit. unfortunatly it gives me `-1` all time.

Answer (score 0):

Every array has a `length` property which returns number of elements in that array:

```
 $(this).click(function() { 
        alert(cubes.length);
 });
```

Comment: `length` is not a function, it's a number property.

Comment: Just like you said, `property`, not `method()`.

Comment: yep, that's obvious. it was a typo

Comment: @jimmyweb no I want the index of the current clicked element in the cubes array

Answer (score 0):

Without any idea what your actual HTML looks like, or how you're constructing your array, the following works (though will, obviously, need to be tailored to your own particular use-case):

```
// creating an array of 'li' elements:
var lis = $('li').map(function(){
    return this;
}).get();

// assigning a click-handler:
$('li').click(function(){
    // using Array.indexOf() to return the index of the 'this' node from the array:
    console.log(lis.indexOf(this));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DDsmc/).

And, to use `$.inArray()` (for those browsers that don't implement `Array.indexOf()`):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    console.log($.inArray(this, lis));
});
```

References:

- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).